"The Fields of a Point Charge in Uniform Motion 1" in Zangwill
In Chapter 20 of Zangwill's Modern Electrodynamics, Application 20.1 the electromagnetic fields for a point charge in uniform motion (velocity $\textbf{v} = v \hat{z}$) along the z-axis is derived. The driving terms are given as
$$\rho(\textbf{r}, t) = q \delta(x) \delta(y) \delta(z - vt)$$
$$\textbf{j}(\textbf{r},t) = \textbf{v} \rho(\textbf{r},t)$$
The solution is solved using potentials in the Lorenz Gauge, meaning that the vector potential satisfies
$$\nabla^2 \textbf{A}_L - \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2 \textbf{A}_L}{\partial t^2} = -\mu_0 \textbf{j} \tag{20.9}$$
Given $\textbf{j}$ is only directed in the z-direction, Zangwill states:

A glance at (20.9) shows that the z-directed current density...produces, at most, a z-directed vector potential

I'm having trouble justifying this claim. I agree that the driving term for $\textbf{A}_L$ is 0 for both x- and y-direction, but does this not just mean that the x- and y- components of $\textbf{A}_L$ satisfy the homogenous wave equation? The homogenous wave equation has non-zero solutions - how do we know that the x- and y- components are not one of these non-zero solutions?
My first thought was that this comes down to uniqueness because the zero solution is the unique solution to the wave equation that decays to 0 at infinity. But given this charge is in motion, I'm not sure how to justify that the solution must decay to 0 at infinity (and, in fact, I do not believe the final solution satisfies this criterion).
The terminology "a glance at" makes me feel the justification is simple given (20.9), but perhaps I am missing something. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
